# Return back to MainActivity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

The `MainActivity` contains some buttons. Each button opens a new activity via an intent. These activities then have a button to return to the `MainActivity` via an intent.

But when I press a button to return to the `MainActivity`, I get some sort of menu on the screen! Someone who knows what could be wrong? Preciate some help! Thanks!

EDIT: The return button in one of the other activities:

```
Button btnReturn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn1);
btnReturn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent returnBtn = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        startActivity(returnBtn);
    }
});
```

The Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kullaberg.test02"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY001" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY002" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY003" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your code of that button.

Comment: Whether you used "android:noHistory=true" in manifest

Comment: provide screenshot , log and some code, because it is hard to understand based on your explaination.....

Comment: I don't think a screenshot would help that much since that is in swedish :)

Comment: are you calling an activity for which setContentView(Blabla.xml) is not set

Comment: Intent returnBtn = new Intent(this,MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(returnBtn); finish();

Answer (score 58, accepted):

why don't you call `finish();`

when you want to return to MainActivity

```
   btnReturn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice..Thanks :)

Comment: finish() actually does not help return to MainActivity, it just closes the current activity

Comment: finish() just destroy your current activity.

Comment: It returns me to `Login` activity instead of `MainActivity` activity.

Answer (score 56):

Here's why you saw the menu with the code you listed in your `onClick` method:

You were creating an Intent with the constructor that takes a string for the action parameter of the `Intent`'s `IntentFilter`. You passed `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` as the argument to that constructor, which specifies that the `Intent` can be satisfied by any `Activity` with an IntentFilter including `<action="android.intent.action.MAIN">`.

When you called `startActivity` with that `Intent`, you effectively told the Android OS to go find an `Activity` (in any app installed on the system) that specifies the `android.intent.action.MAIN` action. When there are multiple Activities that qualify (and there are in this case since *every* app will have a main `Activity` with an `IntentFilter` including the `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` action), the OS presents a menu to let the user choose which app to use.

As to the question of how to get back to your main activity, as with most things, it depends on the specifics of your app. While the accepted answer probably worked in your case, I don't think it's the best solution, and it's probably encouraging you to use a non-idiomatic UI in your Android app. If your `Button`'s `onClick()` method contains *only* a call to `finish()` then you should most likely remove the `Button` from the UI and just let the user push the hardware/software back button, which has the same functionality and is idiomatic for Android. (You'll often see back Buttons used to emulate the behavior of an iOS UINavigationController navigationBar which is discouraged in Android apps).

If your main activity launches a stack of Activities and you want to provide an easy way to get back to the main activity without repeatedly pressing the back button, then you want to call `startActivity` after setting the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` which will close all the Activities in the call stack which are above your main activity and bring your main activity to the top of the call stack. See below (assuming your main activity subclass is called MainActivity:

```
btnReturn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
)};
```

Comment: Very good explanation! For my "return to MainActivity" needs, `startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));` worked perfectly.

Comment: It could be very nice if you explain when we need to use `finish()`.

Comment: You can use `finish()` any time you want to close an Activity. While I suggested not to include a Back button because it's just not necessary on Android and may clutter your UI, it's possible to do so, and there a number of scenarios where you might want to have a widget respond to a touch by doing something and then calling `finish()` an Activity.

Comment: This doesn't actually go back to MainActivity, it starts MainActivity. I'm looking for something that will go back to MainActivity in its current state not start a new activity.

Answer (score 20):

use

```
Intent returnBtn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);

startActivity(returnBtn);
```

make the main activity's `launchmode` to `singleTask` in Android Manifest if you don't want to create new one every time.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. This works just like hitting the back button. It does not lose the main activity's state, while the other answer loses the activity's state.

Comment: Yup this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I had to dig through plenty of different SO posts and finally scroll down to this answer to find what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer. The clear top flag for the intent and this.finish() are both unnecessary, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 13):

I'm used it and worked perfectly...

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

because Finish() use for 2 activities, not for multiple activities

Answer (score 11):

This usually works as well :)

```
navigateUpTo(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: Works very well. Note, you need to call `navigateUpTo` from an `Activity` or `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of starting MainActivity again via startActivity, call finish() instead in the other activities to get back to MainActivity... as MainActivity is already in stack

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on button click in activity and When return back to another activity just finish previous activity by setting flag in intent then put only one Activity in the Stack and destroy the previous one.

```
  Intent i=new Intent("this","YourClassName.Class");
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to your code? It helps the OP and other visitors to understand it. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading the docs on the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. Using it will **not** necessarily go back all the way to the first (`main`) activity. The flag will only remove all existing activities up to the activity class given in the `Intent`. This is explained well in the docs:

```
For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of
activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, 
resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
```

Note that the activity can set to be moved to the foreground (i.e., clearing all other activities on top of it), and then also being relaunched, or only get `onNewIntent()` method called.

[**Source**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

I just do this way

```
public void retorna(View view)
    {
        Intent muda = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

        muda.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       
        startActivity(muda);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.