# Every activity can use "android.intent.action.MAIN"?

Tags: android, android-intent

aid with this example at [Return back to MainActivity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848590/return-back-to-mainactivity-from-another-activity)
I copy that codes as follow,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Activity1"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY001" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY002" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Activity3"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY003" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

So many statements: action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"; if I would use their class path to instead of them, they can also do the job. what's different from these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

its wrong

```
    <action android:name="ACTIVITYNAME FOR INTENT" />


    <category android:name=""/> // android.intent.action.DEFAULT or android.intent.action.MAIN
```

`android.intent.action.MAIN` is given to the activity wich is going to launch at first and

`android.intent.action.OTHER` to the rest of the activities getting called by other activities

Your application will refer to the manifest to fetch the activity for first launch , havin `MAIN` in it

Comment: This answer is completely random. There is no category by the name of "`android.intent.category.MAIN`". The OP was asking about the action "`android.intent.action.MAIN`"

Comment: @price thanx for pointing that. It was a mistake, I have updated that.

Answer (score 0):

setClass() is a explicit declaration, setAction() is a implicit declaration. It will find your target action im manifest.xml.

If the intent-filter with “android.intent.action.MAIN”, there would more entryance of your application, also you can found more icon in launcher.

Comment: are you meaning that setAction() is more good than setClass()?