# Pressing back button calls onCreate (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Activity A starts Activity B.  In Activity B, I have this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this,
                ArticleListActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When I press that home button, it takes me to Activity A as it should.  However, onCreate is being called again.  I do not want this behavior.

I'm guessing its because this implementation uses new Intent to previous item in the navigation stack.  This is just code I got from Eclipse when creating the double pane project though.  I looked around on stack overflow, and though it seems that using an Intent to go back is causing this behavior, I do not understand why Google would provide this in a default template.

How should I make this call differently so that onCreate is not called again when going back to Activity A?

Comment: you can just call onBackPressed()

Comment: Just finish this Activity i.e. call this.finish();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return back to MainActivity from another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848590/return-back-to-mainactivity-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 8):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
       finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

just finish current activity it will take you on previous activity
if your previous activity is activity A then just use finish(); method instead of creating object of intent

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Rajesh you need to call **onBackPressed()**.

Your code detects the home button press and creates a new *ArticleListActivity* class.However, you don't want to create a new class you only want to go back to your already created class/activity. so use *onBackPressed()* instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the launch mode in the manifest, because the parent activity can be popped off the stack.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, the onCreate() is not called again.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```