# How to finish intent after getting values by getExtras?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

I am new at developing Android.I want to finish intent after getting values by getExtras onCreate() method of MainActivity.

EditDetailActivity(startActivity) ----> MainActivity(onCreate)

---

After I updated detail of the item on EditActivity, I am returning to the MainActivty and I update my listview on Mainactivity on onCreate method. Problem is here because it duplicates.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848590/return-back-to-mainactivity-from-another-activity providing the answere to get back to the main activity

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `finish()` in the activity that you want to finish

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

In your case you probably want to call it right after you call `startActivity()` for MainActivity

Comment: I am sorry,the screen (MainActivity) expired after calling finish().My purpose is to clear putExtra values after startActivity().

Comment: That is not what your question says. Why do you even want to clear that? Its data is in the Bundle that is specific for that intent